# Chabad kuntres "Toras Ashkenaz"

Tags: jewish-books, chabad, ashkenazi, yekke

What is the Chabad pamphlet *Toras Ashkenaz: Frankfurt, Germania* ?

Background: A Chabad friend of mine noticed this pamphlet at the Chabad Ohel in Queens. While the title would imply that it is of Jekkisch origin, the other front matter on the cover shows that it is clearly from Lubavitch, being dated both according to the traditional chronology and since the birth of R' M"M Schneerson as well as saying אדמו"ר שליט"א, which I doubt I would ever see used for a dead rebbe outside of Chabad.

The cover reads (with possible errors from photo quality):

> קובץ
>
> **תורת אשכנז**
>
> פראנקפורט, גרמני׳
>
> קובץ א׳ [א]
>
> יום הבהיר יו"ד שבט תשע"ח
>
> **חיים שנה לנשיאות כ"ק אדמו"ר שליט"**

I have no other information about this work.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Title page of Toras Ashkenaz] [image: Second page]

The [Title](https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?146144) says that it is

> יוצא לאור ע"י תלמידים השלוחים דישיבת תות"ל פפד"ם

In short, this is a book of Haoros and Pilpulim written by the student-emissaries (students of Brunoy that were sent to study for a year) in Frankfurt on-the Main.

Comment: This is not the cover that was shown in the photo I saw. I didn't include that photo because I don't have a reshus to do so

Comment: @noach could easily be a different edition

Comment: @DoubleAA, I merely meant that were this info all on the cover, I wouldn't have needed to ask.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, my friend. I hadn't asked if I could share his photo. As it was PM'ed to me, I need specific permission

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt It seems a riddle question until you put a copy, as you ask others to find you a copy of a book only you know the correct answer to.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, I suspect that your answer is correct, but that info isn't on the outside cover. The typeface of the title is identical to the one in the photo.

Comment: Could you either transcribe or translate the relevant portions of the פתח דבר for those who don't have access the images ?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt As DoubleAA said, the pamplet you saw could have been a different edition, which would explain the "shlita" thing you saw. Maybe a Meshichist version.

Answer (score 1):

It is a pamphlet of chiddushim from the students of the Yeshiva Tomchei Temimim Lubavitch of Frankfurt de Main. This is a small satellite Yeshiva of Yeshiva Tomchei Temimim in Brunoy, France. It is comprised of approximately 16-20 bochurim selected from Brunoy who are preparing to go out on shlichut. They do a year or two at Frankfurt.

The pamphlet was composed in 2002 in honor of the 100th birthday of the Rebbe and does use the expression “shlita”.

Your expectation that you wouldn’t see that used after 3 Tammuz 5754 by non-Lubavitchers, however, is not a safe assumption. This practice follows the very old teaching from Rabbi Yehuda HaChassid, one of the leaders of Ashkenazi Chassidim among the Rishonim found in Sefer Chassidim concerning a story in the Talmud about Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi. See the heading *[Post-Talmudic Narratives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_ha-Nasi#Post-Talmudic_narratives)* at Wikipedia.

It says that Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi was buried in his Shabbat clothes and would return to his family every erev Shabbat in order to make kiddish for them. The emphasis being that someone who is dead cannot fulfill the halachic obligation of a mitzvah for those who are living. This is because death frees someone from mitzvah observance (patur min hamitzvot). Even after being buried, Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi had the legal status of being alive, at least at certain auspicious times.

The title page to the pamphlet looks like this:

[image: Title Page Torat Ashkenaz]

This is a link to [the actual pamphlet](https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?146144).

Comment: Have you seen or heard anyone in the last 100 years use "shlita" for someone who was no longer alive at the time, other than the Rebbe?

Comment: @Heshy Thanks for asking. The answer is yes.

Comment: I don't know why you insist that shlita is used outside Lubavitch when the book is clearly written by Lubavitchers (and Meshichistim at that).

Comment: @ShmuelBrin My comments acknowledging the use of 'Shlita' by some Jews with select, departed individuals, apart from those you call Meshichistim, is because I acknowledge reality. It has been done long before the contemporary phenomenon you mention. I hid nothing about the authors of the pamphlet and stated clearly who they were. As to what particular political faction of Lubavitch they are (or were in 2002), I have no knowledge. What I do know is that the Yeshivah in question (in Frankfurt, Germany) is a satellite Yeshivah of the Lubavitcher Yeshivah in Brunei outside of Paris, France.

Comment: @shmuel ...also when the use outside lubavitch, if it exists, is so extremely rare that not expecting it is actually a really really safe assumption, especially in works from the modern period.

Comment: @YaacovDeane But you did not actually bring any support to your claim that the usage of "shlita" for some who passed away is practiced outside of Lubavitch.